# rsa securid token command line windows

Tags: windows, rsa

Is it possible to run RSA SecureID Token (4.1) and get the passcode from Command Line on Windws (Window7)? I know on UNIX you can https://superuser.com/questions/353547/can-i-use-an-rsa-securid-software-token-on-ubuntu-linux

Answer (score 1):

I have found a answer to this... Using AutoHotKey (AutoIt can also be used)... any case I have automated the script - http://code.google.com/p/get-rsa-token-cli/

Also, in case you want to know how I implemented it, use autohotkey script generator